# Delete specific revision from release made with helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, helm3

I'm searching for a way with helm v3 to delete certain revision from given release.

Let's say that I got `my-release` with revision 1,2,2,4 that are automatically created on running `helm upgrade` and deploy new revisions. I can use `helm rollback my-release 3` if I got issues with version 4.

Is there a way to delete specific revision - lets say 1 and 2

helm uninstall my-release 1 is not working unfortunately.

Comment: I dont understand the question. There is only 1 revision being deployed. What do you mean by delete specific revision? Whats the purpose of this?

Comment: ```NAME: my-release
LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Apr 29 08:33:11 2022
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 2
TEST SUITE: None
```

each deployed release has revisions 1,2,3,4. Each time when I upgrade my-release revisions number are incremented and then its possible to revert to different revision number with helm rollback my-release 3

I want to find a way to delete specific revision number because with uninstall the whole release has been removed.

Comment: yes, and what problem do these revision cause you? There is only one active, thats what I mean. So previous revisions are effectivly already uninstalled.

Comment: atm there is no problem but I guess they are consuming disk space. And if certain revision is wrong,  I'm curious is it possible to be deleted.

Comment: revisions are stored in secrets. You can do a kubectl get secrets, and you should see them. But I dont think its a good idea to delete those.  Disk space shouldnt be an issue. This is just a few kb of text. You can also use other backends if you want, like s3 or sql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have a usecase where deleting a revision makes sense in my eyes:

There are 4 revisions:

```
$ helm history rocketchat-b '--namespace' 'rocketchat-b'
REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
40              Fri Nov  3 12:16:38 2023        superseded      rocketchat-1.0.0                        Rollback to 38
43              Tue Nov  7 15:19:02 2023        superseded      rocketchat-6.4.5-1      6.4.5           Upgrade "rocketchat-b" failed: failed to create resource: Ingress.extensions "rocketchat-b-rocketchat" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path: Invalid value: "": must be an absolute path
44              Tue Nov  7 15:19:05 2023        failed          rocketchat-6.4.5-1      6.4.5           Rollback "rocketchat-b" failed: failed to create resource: Ingress.extensions "rocketchat-b-rocketchat" is invalid: spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].path: Invalid value: "": must be an absolute path
45              Tue Nov  7 15:47:31 2023        deployed        rocketchat-6.4.5-1      6.4.5           Upgrade complete
```

There was also a release 39, that one was actually the last one which worked, but it is already deleted automatically (this is what a user potentially wants to avoid). 40 is a deployment of the wrong version, it partially worked, 43 and 44 are complete garbage because port numbers of pod and service don't match. I want to keep 40 now, even when I do some more upgrades (would prefer 39, but that one is gone).
I assume, helm always keeps 4 revisions. maybe not the newest, but chances that 40 stays in my system is bigger if I delete 41 and 42.

I delete these releases by deleting their secret:

```
$ kubectl -n rocketchat-b get secret
NAME                                           TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v40            helm.sh/release.v1                    1      4d22h
sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v43            helm.sh/release.v1                    1      19h
sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v44            helm.sh/release.v1                    1      19h
sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v45            helm.sh/release.v1                    1      18h

$ kubectl -n rocketchat-b delete secret sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v43
secret "sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v43" deleted

$ kubectl -n rocketchat-b delete secret sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v44
secret "sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v44" deleted

$ kubectl -n rocketchat-b get secret
NAME                                           TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v40            helm.sh/release.v1                    1      4d22h
sh.helm.release.v1.rocketchat-b.v45            helm.sh/release.v1                    1      18h
```

What's left is exactly what I want:

```
$ helm history rocketchat-b '--namespace' 'rocketchat-b'
REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS          CHART                   APP VERSION     DESCRIPTION
40              Fri Nov  3 12:16:38 2023        superseded      rocketchat-1.0.0                        Rollback to 38
45              Tue Nov  7 15:47:31 2023        deployed        rocketchat-6.4.5-1      6.4.5           Upgrade complete
```